# check if value in localStrorage is greater than previous value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting an item in localStorage

`{typeof window !== 'undefined' && localStorage.setItem('userData', topic.progress)}`

and then I want to check to see if the value is greater than or less than the previous value, only values greater than should then be set.

However currently it is always changing to the progress value even if the value is lower

my data looks like this :

```
{
topic1: { progress: '20'},
topic2: {progress: '25'},
topic3: {progress: '30'}
}


let progress = ''

  if (localStorage.getItem('userData') !== null && localStorage.getItem('userData') > progress) {
    progress = localStorage.getItem('userData')
  } else if (localStorage.getItem('userData') < progress) {
    console.log('less than')
  }
```

Comment: Local storage is all string-typed. You will need to parse numbers before trying to compare them.

Comment: Also, if you do have multiple `topic`s, you're all writing their progresses into one key.

Comment: [`.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem): _"Returns a DOMString containing the value of the key. If the key does not exist, null is returned."_

Comment: I've changed the data type to string, the idea Is I want to be able to give each topic a progress value, i.e if topic 1 is completed then progress = 20 , topic 3 progress = 30 etc, and strore the progress in localstorage , I need to avoid if the user goes back to topic 1 the progress will decrease as it should always remain the highest progress value

Comment: So, from the above understanding. Is it going to be multiple progresses stored for different topics? It is not very clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by `localStorage.getItem()` is always a string.
You need to **convert the value to a number**, e.g.:

```
const numericLS = parseInt( localStorage.getItem('userData'), 10 );
```

Changing the data type to string everywhere does not help, because string comparison compares character-by-character, not by the numeric value, e.g.:

```
"9" < "89" // false
"9" < "90" // true
```

#### Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('userData', 25);

var progressValues = [ 2, 3, 20, 25, 200, 30 ]; // <--- use numeric values

progressValues.forEach( function( progress ){
  const LS = localStorage.getItem('userData');

  const numericLS = parseInt( LS, 10 );  // <--- convert to number

  if( numericLS < progress ){
    console.log('set larger', progress, ', was', numericLS);
    localStorage.setItem('userData', progress);
  } else {
    console.log('skip smaller', progress, ', keep', numericLS);
  }
})
```